# android gallery app with sliding pictures

Tags: java, android, xml

As in the title. I want to have grid of pictures which consists of 2 columns and every picture must have the same dimensions. The user should be able to click on each picture to enter the full screen mode and then slide pictures from left to right (full sized pictures in that mode). By far, I made a grid of clickable elements but without functionality of sliding them. Here is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.miki.androidtwo.MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_full_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="com.example.miki.androidtwo.FullImageActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="I want to see other doggos" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Other classes are FullImageActivity and ImageAdapter; they are pretty obvious and simple so I won't post them.

1. How can I implement this sliding pictures functionality?
2. How can i determine dimensions of pictures in a grid that will be independent of the device?
   Actually I think I hard-coded it with the line:

   imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(480,402));

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slide the images while they are not full screen, you can use a [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html), or if you want to slide them while they are fullscreen, you can use a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), along with a [PagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html).

So to populate the grid `imageView.setLayoutParams` is fine to use for setting the size of each imageview like the way you did. When a user clicks on an image, you are going to go to a new Activity that is setup with a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter. This way the user can slide through fullscreen images.

Comment: could you give some more hints and idea how to use ViewPager and PagerAdapter? should i put it between ImageView and Button in activity_full_image.xml and appropriate java code in FullImageActivity class?